# sys.getrefcount(None) rolling over to negative value

Tags: python, matplotlib, reference, garbage-collection

So I have a fairly large python application using wxPython, Matplotlib, Numpy, and was originally using pySerial with minimalmodbus for device communication. The application is used to read and plot data from a USB spectroradiometer. All was working well with it until we decided to swap the communications from modbus to usb for speed. I am now using pyusb with libusb0.1 backend. It works for the most part with the exception of a rather annoying:

Fatal Python Error: Deallocating None

This pops up after taking about 20,000 measurements. It's not always on the same one but it's close. After getting the error, I did some googling and decided to  put a sys.getrefcount(None) in my code before and after sending a cmd and receiving data from the USB device. I don't know what numbers are usually to be expected, but there was increase of about 4717 reference count from before the command was sent, till after data was pulled. And a little more than 200,000 increase in reference count from the end of the read till the beginning of the next send. So every measurement increased the reference count by about 220000!

This seems like an outrageous amount to me but then I'm not familiar with the kinds of numbers to be expected here.

The problem is that it seems that whatever variable is holding the reference count for 'None' is a 32 bit signed integer. After about 9000 measurements, the reference count overflows from 2147483647 to -2147483648. It then steadily increases at the same rate as above until it hits zero and kills the program with the aforementioned Fatal Python Error: Deallocating None.

UPDATE:
It turns out that switching from pySerial to pyusb was NOT the source of the problem. I've found that both versions of the application have this same issue only now it's ten times more apparent because of the speed at which I can sample the spectroradiometer using pyusb.

I've removed all conscious uses of numpy from my code although I know matplotib uses numpy pretty heavily and cleaned up a few other areas. This has reduced the rate at which the program fails. I can now get nearly 90,000 measurements before the thing fails but it still does fail. Using the gc library and setting gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK) at the beginning of the program helped my find a lot of these areas that needed fixing. The program spits out a lot of references that seem to be emanating from matplotlib. It repeats this sequence frequently:

```
gc: collectable <MarkerStyle 05575AB0>
gc: collectable <dict 066C8030>
gc: collectable <instancemethod 0532EB70>
gc: collectable <Affine2D 066BE690>
gc: collectable <WeakValueDictionary instance at 066AE300>
gc: collectable <weakref 066C51B0>
gc: collectable <function 066C11F0>
gc: collectable <tuple 066BE350>
gc: collectable <dict 066C85D0>
gc: collectable <list 05134760>
gc: collectable <set 05597C60>
gc: collectable <dict 066C8390>
gc: collectable <MarkerStyle 066BE790>
gc: collectable <dict 066C8540>
gc: collectable <instancemethod 0532EB48>
gc: collectable <Affine2D 066BE7B0>
gc: collectable <WeakValueDictionary instance at 066AEEB8>
gc: collectable <weakref 066C5210>
gc: collectable <function 066C1270>
gc: collectable <tuple 066BE5B0>
gc: collectable <dict 066C8AE0>
gc: collectable <list 051346E8>
gc: collectable <set 05597A80>
gc: collectable <dict 066C88A0>
gc: collectable <MarkerStyle 066BE850>
gc: collectable <dict 066C8A50>
gc: collectable <instancemethod 0532E760>
gc: collectable <Path 066BE870>
gc: collectable <IdentityTransform 066BE890>
gc: collectable <WeakValueDictionary instance at 066C9148>
gc: collectable <weakref 066C5270>
gc: collectable <function 066C12F0>
gc: collectable <tuple 066BE050>
gc: collectable <dict 066C8D20>
gc: collectable <list 05134530>
gc: collectable <set 05597990>
gc: collectable <dict 066C8F60>
```

Just starting the application spews out 967 lines of gc: collectable 'something something'. I don't fully understand how the gc library works or why these are showing up. Am I missing something obvious? How do I get this garbage to disappear?

Comment: Sounds like some module you're using has a reference leak. The refcount for None should not be doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Something in one of the packages (likely `pyusb` since it's the only thing that changed) is not managing the reference count for `None` correctly. It's literally impossible to cause wraparound on a Python object reference count without a reference leak of some kind; the signed `size_t` they use for the reference count can hold `2**31 - 1` or `2**63 - 1` legal values, half the size of the available memory address space in bytes (and in reality, usually the size of the available user mode address space, which is what counts for your purposes). Since the pointers that actually reference it use 4 or 8 bytes a piece, even if you filled all available addresses with references with no other overhead, you'd still never have enough space to store references that could overflow the reference count field. This rules out legal code that is misused (say, storing tons of references in a cache that never gets cleared); it must be a reference leak.

Presumably there is something incrementing it many times per call and not decrementing it later. If you didn't write any Python C extension or `ctypes` code yourself to do this, then it's one of your packages. `pyusb` actually doesn't seem like a likely culprit; it looks like it's implemented in C with some `ctypes` stuff, but it's extremely hard to pass real Python objects to C code that way (and no reason to do so). So presumably you've got at least one package in use that is implemented as a true C extension and was written by someone who doesn't understand CPython referencing counting semantics. I can't begin to guess which one that would be.

Comment: I think "doesn't understand CPython reference counting" is not very generous--it's easy to get manual reference counting wrong by accident, especially if you are writing functions with non-trivial control flow, or if multiple programmers work on the same function.